# Getting text from a website using JSoup

Tags: java, parsing, web, jsoup

I’m working with JSoup to parse the html website.
I want to get the article from (for example) Wikipedia.
I would like to get the text from the main page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) from the table “From today’s featured article”.

Here’s the code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page”);
Elements el = doc.select("div.mp-tfa”);
System.out.println(el);
```

The problem is that it doesn’t work properly - it prints out just a blank line.
The “From today’s featured article” table is inserted in div class=“mp-tfa”.

How to get this text in my java program?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
doc.select("div.mp-tfa");
```

To:

```
doc.select("div#mp-tfa");
```

The better way would to iterate over the `Elements` thus retrieved for the `tag`, `class` or `Element` of your choice, simply put:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page").get();
Elements el = doc.select("div#mp-tfa");
for (Element e : el) {
    System.out.println(e.text());
}
```

Would give:

```
The Boulonnais is a heavy draft horse breed from Fr....
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's supposed to be:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page").get();
Elements el = doc.select("div#mp-tfa");
System.out.println(el);
```

Comment: Glad to help, although PopoFibo's answer is more comprehensive. :)